# Pipeline step is failing with "fatal: reference is not a tree: 679e2fc3c2590f7dbaf64534a325ac60b4dc8689"

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

One of my step in my pipeline is failing with the below error:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: 679e2fc3c2590f7dbaf64534a325ac60b4dc8689
```

How do i resolve this error? even after re-triggering the step, it is failing with the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a result of `git push --force`  or  `git rebase`, which deletes the commit and causes the pipeline to lose the pointer to the change and finally not run.

You can resolve this by either doing:

- A Reset the resource in JFrog Pipelines and then trigger a run.

> Note that if there are several GitRepo resources in the pipeline, this
> needs to be done for all of them.

- Push another commit so that all the resources are updated automatically.